# Узнать имя макроса в шаблоне UMI

Tags: tpl, umi

Значит есть модуль например с полями title, h1, photo, price

С глобальными макросами понятно, подставляю %title%,%ketwords% и т.п. в файл tpl
А как узнать имя макроса у собственных полей(price,photo) ?
Т.е. что подставлять %сюда% ?

Answer (score 1):

Насколько понимаю, речь идёт о TPL-шаблонизаторе UMI.CMS.

Для вывода значения свойства существует макрос [`%data getProperty()%`](http://dev.docs.umi-cms.ru/spravochnik_makrosov_umicms/shablony_dannyh/data_getproperty/)

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?